# Language Selection in Flutter with L10N - Preferred or Auto System

Tags: flutter, user-interface, localization, multilingual

I have an app that I'm translating to different languages using Flutter L10N.
I have this in my MaterialApp:

```
localizationsDelegates: const [
    AppLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
],
supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales
```

and it works, but the language is automatically set to device language.
I want to select the language using a dropdown box, but also have the option to auto-select it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: You can use my approach https://github.com/IvanovYevgen/setup_pr Just get local from state of cubit. But it is possible to write more complicated code, when you will preserve user's local on server and get it accordingly user's choice.

Answer (score 1):

Just read [this](https://medium.com/@echolaojue/how-to-make-l10n-with-flutter-fd61e21e61d8) post on Medium. It's pretty simple describes how to make your app translated with multiple languages.

On **Step 9** you can find the `LocaleProvider` code, with which it's possible to switch between languages in your app.

Comment: I already have a Consumer<ThemeProvider> as child of a MultiProvider to control theming, how do I make it work with another Consumer<LocaleProvider>?